# Probability of correct classification with optimal Bayes when increasing number of features

Tags: probability, naive-bayes, optimal

Consider the optimal Bayes classifier applied on a problem with N features. Let its probability of correct classification be $$P_N(corr)$$ Assume that we add an extra feature (so now we have N + 1 features) and again design the Bayes classifier. Let its probability of correct classification be $$P_N+1(corr)$$ Prove that
$$P_N+1(corr) \leqslant P_N(corr)$$

Comment: if this is HW please add the self-study tag